# IBM integration bus: A SOAP request received an HTTP Error Status Code '500'

Tags: json, http, soap, wsdl, ibm-integration-bus

I'm new to Ibm Integration Bus, and I've been struggling to convert Data from http nodes to SOAP nodes.
[My message Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w70D6.png)

The problem is when I use SOAP input it works but when I change it with Http input and convert the data from JSON to XML, an error keeps showing up.

code of compute node:

```
     DECLARE reftoOut REFERENCE To OutputRoot.XMLNSC.ns2:MessageExtraitRequest;
     DECLARE reftoIn REFERENCE To InputRoot.JSON.Data;
        
        
        SET reftoOut.ns2:No_du_compte = reftoIn.No_du_compte;
        SET reftoOut.ns2:Date_operation = reftoIn.Date_operation;
        SET reftoOut.ns2:REFERENCE = reftoIn.REFERENCE;
        SET reftoOut.ns2:Libelle = reftoIn.Libelle;
        SET reftoOut.ns2:Date_valeur = reftoIn.Date_valeur;
        SET reftoOut.ns2:DEBIT = reftoIn.DEBIT;
        SET reftoOut.ns2:CREDIT = reftoIn.CREDIT;
```

my WSDL ( it works just fine with SOAPInput and postman)

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!-- <definitions> must be the root of the WSDL document --> <wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/"    xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"    xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"    xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"    xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/"    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"    xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/"    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">   <!-- WSDL TYPES: definition of the data types that are used in the web service -->   <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
      <s:element name="MessageExtraitRequest">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="No_du_compte" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Date_operation" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="REFERENCE" type="s:int"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Libelle" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Date_valeur" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="DEBIT" type="s:int"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CREDIT" type="s:int"/>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="MessageExtraitResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="fieldCount" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="affectedRows" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="insertId" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="serverStatus" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="warningCount" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="message" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="protocol41" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="changedRows" type="s:string"/>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
    </s:schema>   </wsdl:types>   <!-- MESSAGES: defines the data being exchanged between the service and client -->   <wsdl:message name="MessageExtraitSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:MessageExtraitRequest"/>   </wsdl:message>   <wsdl:message name="MessageExtraitSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:MessageExtraitResponse"/>   </wsdl:message>   <!-- PORT TYPES: defines the complete communication operation (one way/round trip) -->   <wsdl:portType name="MessageExtraitSoapPort">
    <!-- The operation name must be the same as the one specified in the service object -->
    <wsdl:operation name="MessageExtrait">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:MessageExtraitSoapIn"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:MessageExtraitSoapOut"/>
    </wsdl:operation>   </wsdl:portType>   <!-- BINDING: provides details on how a portType operation will actually be transmitted -->   <wsdl:binding name="MessageExtraitServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:MessageExtraitSoapPort">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="MessageExtrait">
      <soap:operation soapAction="MessageExtrait" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>   </wsdl:binding>
     <!-- SERVICE:  -->   <wsdl:service name="MessageExtraitService">
    <wsdl:port name="MessageExtraitServiceSoapPort" binding="tns:MessageExtraitServiceSoapBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8000/wsdl"/>
    </wsdl:port>   </wsdl:service> </wsdl:definitions>
```

The error:

```
    Error sending request to http "http://localhost:7800/server"
            java.io.IOException: {"error": {"code":500,"status":"Internal Server Error","detail":"BIP2230E: Error detected whilst processing a message in node 'WS_MF.
        SOAP Request'. \nBIP3754E: The SOAP Request Node or SOAP Async Request Node WS_MF.
        SOAP Request encountered an error while processing the outbound SOAP request. \nBIP3162S: An HTTP error occurred. 
        The HTTP Request-Line was: ''POST /wsdl HTTP/1.1
            \nBIP3711E: A SOAP request received an HTTP Error Status Code '500', but the response message body was not a SOAP fault. 
        The HTTP  request was made to the destination ''http://localhost:8000/wsdl''. 
        The HTTP status line that was returned was: ''HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error''. \nBIP3701E: A Java exception was thrown whilst calling the Java JNI method ''Axis2Requester_processResponseMessageSync''. 
        The Java exception was ''org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x45) was found in the prolog of the document.''. 
        The Java stack trace was ''Frame : 0 org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x45) was found in the prolog of the document.
    | @: org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:293)| 
    @: org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelope(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:204)
    | @: org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:154)
    | @: org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:140)
    | @: com.ibm.broker.axis2.SoapUtilities.createSOAPMessage(SoapUtilities.java:2259)
    | @: com.ibm.broker.axis2.SoapUtilities.createSOAPMessage(SoapUtilities.java:1959)
    | @: com.ibm.broker.axis2.Axis2Requester.processResponseMessageSync(Axis2Requester.java:2184)|Frame : 1 javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x45) was found in the prolog of the document.
    | @: com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.stax.msg.StAXMessageProvider.throwWrappedXMLStreamException(StAXMessageProvider.java:76)
    | @: com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.stax.XMLStreamReaderImpl.produceFatalErrorEvent(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:2008)
    | @: com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.jaxb.JAXBXMLStreamReader.produceFatalErrorEvent(JAXBXMLStreamReader.java:356)| @: com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.scan.DocumentScanner.reportFatalError(DocumentScanner.java:4871)| @: com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.scan.DocumentScanner.reportFatalError(DocumentScanner.java:1212)| @: com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.scan.DocumentScanner.scanProlog(DocumentScanner.java:1777)| @: com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.scan.DocumentScanner.nextEvent(DocumentScanner.java:1323)| @: com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.stax.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:581)| @: com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.stax.XMLInputFactoryImpl$XMLStreamReaderProxyImpl.next(XMLInputFactoryImpl.java:183)| @: com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.wssec.WSSXMLInputFactory$WSSStreamReaderProxy.next(WSSXMLInputFactory.java:55)| @: org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:672)| @: org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
| @: org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.getSOAPEnvelope(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:204)
| @: org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:154)
| @: org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder.<init>(StAXSOAPModelBuilder.java:140)
| @: com.ibm.broker.axis2.SoapUtilities.createSOAPMessage(SoapUtilities.java:2259)
| @: com.ibm.broker.axis2.SoapUtilities.createSOAPMessage(SoapUtilities.java:1959)
| @: com.ibm.broker.axis2.Axis2Requester.processResponseMessageSync(Axis2Requester.java:2184)''. "}}
                at com.ibm.etools.mft.unittest.core.transport.http.HttpClient.makeHttpCall(HttpClient.java:163)
                at com.ibm.etools.mft.unittest.core.transport.http.HttpClient.makeSOAPRequest(HttpClient.java:99)
                at com.ibm.etools.mft.unittest.core.transport.http.SendHTTPMessageDelegate.sendBytes(SendHTTPMessageDelegate.java:125)
                at com.ibm.etools.mft.unittest.core.commchannel.mb.AbstractSendMessageDelegate.sendPlainText(AbstractSendMessageDelegate.java:255)
                at com.ibm.etools.mft.unittest.core.commchannel.mb.AbstractSendMessageDelegate.sendMessage(AbstractSendMessageDelegate.java:208)
                at com.ibm.etools.mft.unittest.core.transport.http.HTTPHandler.send(HTTPHandler.java:53)
                at com.ibm.etools.mft.unittest.core.commchannel.mb.SendMessageOperation.sendMessage(SendMessageOperation.java:87)
                at com.ibm.etools.mft.unittest.core.commchannel.jobs.SendMessageOperationJob.doRun(SendMessageOperationJob.java:94)
                at com.ibm.etools.mft.unittest.core.commchannel.jobs.SendMessageOperationJob.run(SendMessageOperationJob.java:149)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: You might want to add the tags "WSDL" and "SOAP" to get more exposure for your question. Also, consider added "IBM integration bus" to the question header.

Comment: I added them, thanks.

Comment: Your picture of the flow does not contain a node with name `WS_MF`, so the error message does not match the drawing of your flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important bits of the error message are:

```
BIP3754E: The SOAP Request Node or SOAP Async Request Node WS_MF
          encountered an error while processing the outbound SOAP request.

BIP3711E: A SOAP request received an HTTP Error Status Code '500',
          but the response message body was not a SOAP fault.
```

In other words: The reply of endpoint `http://localhost:8000/wsdl` is not valid SOAP reply; maybe it is plain text. You should analyse this endpoint and figure out why it is not replying a proper SOAP reply.